# Magit status Recent commits foreground color

Tags: magit

I have a terminal with a dark background color. Magit shows recent commits and uses a dark color for the commit hashes so I can't see them. I tried customizing frame-background-mode to be dark but the hashes are still not visible. Any way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `M-x describe-char` with point on a commit hash, you can see various informations about the character, including its *face*:

> There are text properties here:
>
> face                 magit-hash

Now you can move the point (using the TAB key) to the face name and type the RETURN key (or click on the words `magit-hash`) to get the face's documentation.  This shows that the only *attribute* of the face is the foreground color, that happens to be `grey60`.  This also includes a link `customize this face` that will allow you to change this color.

Use `Choose` then `Apply` or `Apply and Save` to make the change apply to future sessions (it will be saved in your init file).

For more information about faces, see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.